# create a dynamic expandable table by using angularjs and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, expandable-table

I'd like to create an expandable table by using JQuery: http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#examples.

The issue is that there is a conflict between angularjs and jquery. This is my html file:

```
<table>
   <tbody ng-repeat="row in construct.matrix.rows">
      <tr data-tt-id="row.name">
         <td>{{row.name}}</td>
         <td>
            <button ng-click="newField($index)">Add a Field</button>
            <form ng-submit="addField($index, fieldName, row)" ng-if="choose($index)">
               <input type="text" ng-model="fieldName" name="text" placeholder="New Field" />
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

To use the jquery part i use this tag :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   initialize();
});

function initialize() {
   $("table").agikiTreeTable({
      persist : false,
      persistStoreName : "files"
   });
}
```

I'd like to have a simple table at the beginning with only one row. On this row, the user can click on a button and then submit a new row which will be an expandable row from the first one. Just to see if it was possible, I tried to do so but I understood that I had to recall the initialize function after submitting the first expandable row. And it works, but if I want to do the operation again I have some conflicts.

Look at this picture:

[image: conflict when I redo the operation]

So if anyone has an idea to fix this, I will be glad to hear it. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you just create a snippet or bin? it will much easier for us to help you that way.

Comment: Thanks for your help but @beaver solved my problem. I just wanted to create a dynamic table but i didn't know that i could use only angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using Angular libraries and avoid jQuery based components?

Here are some alternatives:

- http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid
- http://thienhung1989.github.io/angular-tree-dnd/demo/#/basic
- http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html
- http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/table-example

Comment: Thanks i looked for something like this for hours

Comment: So i chose this solution : http://thienhung1989.github.io/angular-tree-dnd/demo/#/basic and this is very useful but i don't find how to reload data so if you have any idea it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Reload data? Do you mean update the UI after data change? Please share your code relating data updating, tree table sourcing and code useful to reproduce your problem

Comment: Yes this is what i meant. But it's ok i found how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the ng-table library, it has grouping functionality built in:

http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-grouping-basic